# Solving for a Nested Square Root

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm a high school student preparing for the AMC and AIME and I ran across this problem that I can't solve. I have solved similar problems, but this one I just can't seem to figure out:
What is $X$ in:
$$X=\displaystyle\sqrt{2\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt[4]{2\sqrt[5]{2\sqrt[6]{2 .....}}}}}$$

Btw, since it is for AMC and AIME I need to do it without the use of a calculator.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite $X$ as

$$2^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot 2^{\frac{1}{6}} \cdot 2^{\frac{1}{24}} \cdot 2^{\frac{1}{120}} \cdot \ldots = 2^{A}$$

where $$A = \displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{k!} = e - 2$$

$$\therefore X=2^{e-2}$$

Comment: By the way, by definition, $\sum _{ k=0 }^{ \infty }{ \frac { 1 }{ k! } } =e$